# Database design for interrelated group/list

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am creating the combat sports statistics site. I have trouble designing the database which would hold the specific bout statistics e.g. the way the fight was finished.

It can be very straightforward:

```
-> Decision
```

or

```
-> Decision -> Unanimous
```

or

```
-> Decision -> Unanimous -> 30-27, 29-28, 29-28
```

or

```
-> Submission -> Armbar
```

In this case we have a simple tree (each item can have one or more children) and it can be implemented by the simple `(id, "Name", parent_id)` organization. In it, for each fight I assign some unique bout-finish-id and go up the tree to make a proper chain with parents, links and all.

Unfortunately the situation can also be a little more complex with some of the items having more than one parent:

```
-> Submission -> Armbar -> Armbar triangle  
-> Submission -> Triangle -> Armbar triangle
```

This should be pretty easy as "Armbar triangle" is clearly the child of both "Armbar" and "Triangle". But I am already lost at this point and don't quite understand how to design this multiparent list properly.

But there is more.

There is a ton of other statistics. For example all other details of that said finish. In case of KO/TKO victory, this might be some information about each fighter stances (lefty, righty, neutral), specific strike, info about movement, the hit area etc. Something like "TKO. Forward moving upward right elbow from righty-position to left side of jaw of the backing lefty-opponent.".

If we talk about the submissions, let's talk about the simple example of position.

```
-> Submission -> Triangle -> Armbar triangle -> Guard position
```

or

```
-> Submission -> Triangle -> Armbar triangle -> Mount position
```

But here the problem is that Guard or Mount can be at any point of this chain. All of the following are correct:

```
-> Submission -> Triangle -> Guard position -> Armbar triangle  
-> Submission -> Guard position -> Triangle -> Armbar triangle  
-> Guard position -> Submission -> Triangle -> Armbar triangle
```

Here we get the problem of some of the items being interrelated which basically means that one could go on and on in an endless loop. This is obviously a huge problem in both database design and rendering.

I can't put the info in some specific order (for example put the position always to the end) because I want to be able to click at each entry and be able to see all the parents/children that relate to this entry.

The only thing I could think of was a full separation of different information (different list for submissions, strikes, decisions, stances, positions, hit targets, etc). Then I create a tag-like list where I could put as much "fight-ending tags" as I like. Is this the only proper way to achieve what I want?

But then it would mean that I can't easily check for example all the "Triangles from Guard" or I would need to make an elaborate system of tag combination...

But that's not all.

I would also like to be able to save the chains of events that lead to a finish.

```
-> Loser's (righty) left hook to winner (lefty)'s right jaw -> Loser's Ground and Pound from Guard -> Winner's Armbar triangle from Mount
```

This is the example of the description, that can only contain the previously defined "proper finishes".

And now that we are at it and I have the opportunity to tell about my dream system (regardless of whether or not it is implementable), it would be nice to be able to include all the details which aren't in the "official finishing list" like "Slip to right", "Double leg takedown", "Hipbump sweep/reversal" and what not.

Believe it or not, but there is even more than that... Even if we forget about the last wish (about slips and takedowns), I would really like to be able to rate the items in the chain of events according to the level they influenced the outcome. For example from 1 to 3. Something like:

```
-> Loser's (righty) left hook to winner (lefty)'s right jaw (3) -> Loser's Ground and Pound from Guard (1) -> Winner's Armbar triangle from Guard (3)
```

I want to make this feature properly and I want to implement it correctly from the beginning. But I feel like I overcomplicate this issue. I feel like I went waaaaaay over the top with my fantasies, but can't seem to stop. Is there any way to create the proper database structure according to all my wishes? What kind of table/row structure should I choose? Or should I simply forget this craziness and scale it down to a reasonable (whatever this means) setup? So what would be a reasonable solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your subject domain, but reading your question threw up a few ideas.

First, don't implement an "elaborate system of tag combination" if you want to find specific events. In terms of database structure, this normally means a comma delimited list which is very much a no-no in SQL.

Better you should have one table of bouts and a second table of events which are connected to the bout. You would need to define a third table which holds all possible events (left hook to right jaw, right hook to left jaw) with associated id numbers, and a fourth table of competitors with id. Then your bout table would consists of information regarding the bout itself (place, date, etc) along with the ids of the competitors. The events/bout table would consist of the bout's id, the time of the event within the bout, the id of which competitor performed the action, and the id of the event itself.